# Multi Site any page getting 404 any time

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.0.1, multistore, cache

I am working on multi-site store but I have found I am getting 404 error page for second store any time and any page but after refresh that page works fine.

After investigating this I have found that if I disable configuration cache than all problems have been resolved.

Is that module specific issue or other? I am not getting that. Anyone have an idea?

Comment: I have find in cache problem if i have disable configuration cache than i has been resolved.